# npm publish: how to ignore hooks

Tags: node.js, npm, nexus

I'm trying to store React project dependencies in Nexus. The Nexus resides in local area network which is disconnected from internet. Thus I have to manually upload and maintain all the NPM dependencies in Nexus. I created new hosted NPM repository and the following script to upload the packages after running `npm install` in online mode.

```
#!/bin/bash

nexus='http://192.168.1.111:8082/nexus/repository/npm-releases/'
project="$PWD"

pkgs=$(find node_modules -type f -name 'package.json')
for pkg in $pkgs
do
  cd "$(dirname "$pkg")"
  echo $PWD
  npm publish --registry "${nexus}"
  cd "$project"
done;
```

However, some of these packages contains publish hooks which tries to push to git etc. How do I ignore all these hooks? Secondly, it takes approximately 45 minutes for this script to upload all the packages. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a curl into your script you could use the REST API.

Here's an example in the latest NXRM3:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/components?repository=npm-hosted" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "npm.asset=@crc-3.0.0.tgz;type=application/gzip"
```

I think that'll bypass the hooks and I also suspect the hooks might be what are causing the delay.